# Squarespace suddenly does not work

Tags: domain

I am a Google Domain website owner. In 2023, Google Domains is being migrated to Squarespace. During this time, They sent me a link to Squarespace, and for months I have logged into Squarespace successfully, and I am able to view my domains.

Today, I am no longer able to log into Squarespace account.

I have attempted an account recovery using my phone number and email addresses, but no message is ever received on my phone or email inboxes.

I have tried:

- Restart PC
- 2 browsers
- Disable all adblockers and other extensions
- Using Incognito Mode
- Clear Cookies and Cache
- Allow Browser Notifications
- Used both Squarespace Web and mobile App versions

SquareSpace only provides email support, and they have not helped me get back into my account, after several conversations.

Why did it work for months, and how do I get into my account now?